# SQL query to get rows where ID is the same based on remaining contents

Tags: sql, postgresql

for the purpose of this example let's say I have a fairly simple table:

```
-----------
| ID | Val|
-----------
| 01 | XX |
| 01 | YY |
| 03 | AA |
| 04 | XX |
| 02 | BB |
| 02 | AA |
| 03 | XX |
| 02 | XX |
-----------
```

And what I want to select is the IDs where Val has `XX` and `AA` so basically my result would be `03` and `02` because they are the only IDs with Vals that have both of those values. Even though `02` also has `BB` and even though `01` an `04` also have `XX`.

I am just a bit stumped as to how to write this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method for Postgres:

```
select id
from t
where val = any(array['XX', 'AA'])
group by id
having count(*) = cardinality(array['XX', 'AA']);
```

Note that this allows you to pass in the values of interest as an array.  Only one array parameter is needed, regardless of the number of values.

If duplicates are allowed, you will need `count(distinct val)` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: I am a little bit confused here if it will consider the scenario where ID with two rows and in both rows, val is `'AA'`

Comment: Thankfully the table I have does contain exclusively distinct Vals by IDs, so the answer works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using aggregation:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE Val IN ('XX', 'AA')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(Val) <> MAX(Val);
```

The idea here is to aggregate by `ID`, restricting to only the `XX` and `AA` values, then assert that there are in fact two different values.  If the assertion passes, then it implies that the `ID` has both values.

Note that the above query can take advantage of an index on `(ID, Val)`, because of the way the `HAVING` clause is written.

Comment: Awesome thank you, did not know it would be such a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this:

```
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
WHERE Val IN ('XX', 'AA')
GROUP BY ID
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT VAL) = 2;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Yes, I was about to change it.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You want a result set that is an intersection of two sets:

```
select ID
from yourTable
where Val in ("XX")
intersect
select ID
from yourTable
where Val in ("AA")
```